# MUnit test debug breakpoints in Workbench not working

Tags: workbench, debugging

When I create a breakpoint in Workbench 2 for an MUnit test, and run a debug build, the breakpoints are not breaking execution. The MUnit output is updated like a normal run without breakpoints. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set breakpoints in what is considered a source file, ie a .m package file. Breakpoints set within test or scrapbook files are not supported.

So you would have a test that executes a function defined in a package, set the breakpoint in the package, and when you debug the test, it will suspend.